# CORS policy don't want to work with SignalR and ASP.NET core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors, signalr, angular7

I have a problem with my ASP.NET core API and my Angular Client. I want to implement SignalR to have a connection between API and Angular. The cors policy are already activated on our client and the API because we can already retrieve data from the API with our client. But the problem now is when I try to use SignalR I receive an error with CORS POLICY:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:50501/CoordinatorHub/negotiate' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

But there's already cors policy inside the Startup.cs on our API and it's like that:

In the ConfigureServices method :

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder => 
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/")
            .AllowCredentials()
            //.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains());
});
```

And inside the Configure method :

```
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
```

In our Client we just want to try to make a connection between the API and the client and it's like that:

```
this.hubConnection.start({withCredentials: false}).then(() => 
     this.hubConnection.invoke('send', 'Hello'));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS policy issue with angular 7 and ASP.NET core 2.2 using SIGNAL R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808822/cors-policy-issue-with-angular-7-and-asp-net-core-2-2-using-signal-r)

Comment: I had the same problem, and i was not able to solve it.

Comment: Same issue, have you figured it out?  Best help I found was this, which is what you already have in ConfigureServices: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2095

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I solved my problem according to this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4457#issuecomment-465669576)

Add this block code to service

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                   .AllowCredentials();
        }));
```

and add this block code in configuring app

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<General>("/hubs/general");
        });
```

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer did not work for me so I decided to put down here what worked for me. In case someone stumbles across the same issue.

I was facing same issue in my local testing while playing around with signalR  on Angular 9.

I solved it by switching my Asp NET Core (3.1) app URL from https to http. if you are using Visual Studio,

1. just right click on project properties -> Debug.
2. Uncheck Enable SSL

[image: Asp Net core Project]

Also do not forget to change the port on your URL in angular App. So basically URL in angular app will be something like this

```
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:50782/hub").build();
```

whereas the relevant code in Configure method is something like this

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

   
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("_myAllowSpecificOrigins");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/hub");
});
```

and in your configureServices method I had following

```
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("_myAllowSpecificOrigins",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200")
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .SetIsOriginAllowed((x) => true)
                           .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });
    
   services.AddSignalR();
```

Hope this helps !

**UPDATE**

if you are just playing around with samples on your local machine you can also try to run chrome in security mode as mentioned [here](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/)

on my mac I just simply ran command from terminal

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security
```

With this you should be able to run your sample without CORS bothering

Comment: You sir saved me 3 hours deep into the mix, I was looking for a solution that didnt require setting a proxy on the angular side. Thanks!

Comment: Another option that I found after digging a little deeper was this,

                        ```builder
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials()
                            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost");```

Comment: I tried your steps @kuldeep but I'm getting error as "http://localhost:64574/api/location/negotiate" ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

PS: I'm using ionic, and trying to hit the api from android emulator.

Comment: I do not know about ionic, is it  browser based ? i suggest if yes then you open the chrome in security mode like i have suggested, OR you can set your API to allow localhost in cors policy like the comment above !

Comment: For me it was the order of the instructions. Moving them to follow the above order worked.

Answer (score 10):

**Note** this can be applied to .net   core 3.1

As it's stated on microsoft docs it seems doesn't work 
 [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Preceding code ommitted.
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    // Following code ommited.
}
```

> Warning
>
> With endpoint routing, the CORS middleware must be configured to
>   execute between the calls to UseRouting and UseEndpoints. Incorrect
>   configuration will cause the middleware to stop functioning correctly.

But if you move your UseCors() in the first place your application will work as expected so  the working code will be

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
//place your useCors here 
    app.UseCors();
    app.UseRouting();


    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    // Following code ommited.
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Running the server produced an error stating that UseCors must be placed between UseRouting and UseEndpoints (as indicated in the documentation)

Answer (score 8):

After doing a lot of research I also would like to share what I have faced and how I fixed it.

My scenario was; I deployed my `.Net Core` app on `Azure App Services` along with `Azure SignalR` configuration. Everything was working fine when I run both frontend and backend on my local machine. But when I deploy my app on azure services, I could not be able to connect due to this `../Hub/negotiate` and cors issue.

How I fixed; First make sure you already enabled cors settings in your api as friends indicated here. I took my example signalR apps from Microsoft docs in this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/samples). Finally I realized that in project examples the `@aspnet/signalr@1.0.0` package is outdated and moved to `@microsoft/signalr`. And In my research I saw in some places that `withCredentials` should be set to false because by default this value is true and forces the connection to use SSL. My client app is running on local with http and trying to connect https connection. For more of this, refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials). In the old signalR npm package this value wasn't set, so as soon as I switched to the new one, `withCredentials` attribute activated and I set it false. All started working fine.

My final hub builder is like this;

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl('https://**chat.azurewebsites.net/chat', {
                accessTokenFactory: () => 'InR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6I',
                withCredentials: false
            }).build();
```

Comment: withCredentials: false

this worked for me. thanks!

Comment: Works for me to. Thks!!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem that I struggled with for 6 hours.

It turned out that I had a slash at the end of my Origins.

So instead of:

```
.WithOrigins("https://aaa.azurewebsites.net/")
```

use:

```
.WithOrigins("https://aaa.azurewebsites.net")
```

Why the final slash isn't just stripped is beyond my understanding.

Comment: Same issue, solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try something like this in your startup configuration class:

```
app.Map("/CoordinatorHub/negotiate", map =>
{
    map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration 
    {
        // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
    // EnableDetailedErrors = true,
        // EnableJSONP = true

    };
    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
});
```

Comment: Isn't that for 'ASP.NET SignalR' rather than 'ASP.NET Core SignalR' (?).

Comment: ASP.NET Core SignalR

Comment: But I'm wondering if that was an old arrangement, because I thought the 'HubConfiguration' wasn't available anymore (- 'ObsoleteOwinExtensions'?), and you now call  'AddSignalR()' and 'MapHub()' instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Tested on signalR in .Net Core 3.1+ and Angular 8+ versions and android 19+ api level and working on iOS devices too**

**.Net core code**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                );
            });


            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddAccessTokenService();
            services.AddSignalR()
                 .AddHubOptions<ChatHub>(options => options.EnableDetailedErrors = true)
                 .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
                 {
                     options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                  }); ;
            services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();

        }



public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
            });

        }
```

--Angular code replace url and token(optional part) with and it's working--

```
public startConnection = () => {
  this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                          .withUrl(this.url,{ accessTokenFactory: () => this.token},)
                          .build();

  this.hubConnection
    .start()
    .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
    .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err))
}

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.startConnection();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently i have face the same issue for .Net Core 3.1, Issue start when i deploy in Azure App service and lastly able to solve the issue use the following code.

I use the following code in ConfigureServices function on Startup.cs file

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            var corsUrls = Configuration.GetSection("App:CorsOrigins").Value.ToString()
                      .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                             .Select(o => o.Trim('/'))
                             .ToArray();
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(corsUrls)
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
```

Then add the following code in Configure function

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<WebhookHub>("/Webhook");
  });
```

Don't forgot to add the following section in appsetting.json file

```
"App": {
"CorsOrigins": "https://myservice.com" }
```